# can defadvice use variables in the original function?

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

Let me take the modified example from [Emacs Lisp: How to use ad-get-arg and ad-get-args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622351/emacs-lisp-how-to-use-ad-get-arg-and-ad-get-args)

```
(defun my-add (a b &optional c)
  (+ a b)
  (unless c
    (setq c 4)))
(defadvice my-add (after my-log-on (a b &optional c) activate)
  (message "my-add a: %s" a)
  (message "my-add: %s" c))
```

`(my-add 1 2 3)` will run well with output:

```
my-add a: 1
my-add: 3
```

but `(my-add 1 2)` cannot get the `c` value from original function:

```
my-add a: 1
my-add: nil
```

My question is how can I use optional arguments not provided (or more generally, the variables in the original function) in the `defadvice` body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't.  `defadvice` (as well as the new `advice-add`) is designed to add code **around** a function, but does not give you access to its internals.

Answer (score 1):

Since `(setq c 4)` from `my-add` changes the environments, not given parameter, I think you cannot get what you want.

My best bet is following ugly way using special variable:

```
(defvar *special*)
(defun my-add (a b &optional c)
  (+ a b)
  (unless c
    (setq c 4)
    (setq *special* 4)))

(defadvice my-add (after my-log-on (a b &optional c) activate)
  (message "my-add a: %s" a)
  (if (null c)
      (message "my-add *special*: %s" *special*)
    (message "my-add: %s" c)))
```